# How Do I avoid objects while following a random path? Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I have an enemy object set up to move toward random nodes in a 2d maze environment. The only issue I'm having is keeping the enemy from squeezing through collision walls like a Roach. Here is the code I followed along from a tutorial to move the enemy around with the way points. All help is appreciated, its been almost a week now since I've been trying to wrap my head around this!

```
    public class Enemy_AI : MonoBehaviour {

     public float speed;
     public float waitTime;
     public float startWaitTime;

     public Transform[] moveSpots;
     private int randomSpot;

     private void Start()
     {
         randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
         waitTime = startWaitTime;
     }

     void Update()
     {
         transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

         if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position) < 0.2f)
         {
             if(waitTime <= 0)
             {
                 randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
                 waitTime = startWaitTime;
             }

             else
             {
                 waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
             }

         }

     }

 }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you should use [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html), a raycast can detect if there is a object between a given position and a direction, you can also pass the lenght of the ray and which object layers should be considered.

Having in mind that your code could be something like the following:

```
public LayerMask mask;
 void Update()
 {

     RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position, 0.2f, mask);
     if(!hit)
     {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

     }
     if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position) < 0.2f)
     {
         if(waitTime <= 0)
         {
             randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
             waitTime = startWaitTime;
         }

         else
         {
             waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
         }

     }   
    }
```

With the mask in the inspector you can select the elements that will be used as collisions in the ray, so your "Obstacles" should be marked there (and have their own layers)

For debugging if there is any place to move you can do something like this:

```
if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position) < 0.2f)
{
// as it is
}
else
{
    bool canMove = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < moveSpots.Lenght;i++)
    {
       if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[i].position) < 0.2f)
       {
           canMove = true;
       }
    }
    Debug.Log("Is avaliable any move?" + canMove);
}
```

Comment: Hi Chopi, Thank you for your response! Well it seems like everything is working ok, my enemy object continues to patrol the way points but it seems to still cut a few corners but its better than before though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Uhmm have you checked that corners?? Do they have the correct layer and a collider?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to Unity so there may be a mistake that I might have missed. I've updated my post with a screenshot of the object properties for my collision masks.

Comment: Instead of tag use the layer, it is in the right of the tag field.

Comment: Upload also a picture of the enemy component

Comment: I Just uploaded the enemy component above. I've noticed after changing from tag to layers like you mentioned before, it works much better now. The enemy "Hexegon" doesn't go through walls anymore however it does get stuck on the walls because it can't properly navigate through the maze.

Comment: In the ray change 1.0 to 0.2f

Comment: It has improved a tad bit but still with the same issue, do you need me to send you my project?

Comment: Can you try to debug it?? Can be happening that there is no way to move?? Make a else for the !hit if and make a loop showing the distance between the two points. If all options returns something bigger than 0.2f the  Ai can't move.

Comment: @user1656528 check my answer i've updated it with the debug thing, I would do something similar to that in order to check that there is no way to move.

Comment: If I have implemented your code correctly it seems like my object is "Not" moving since I don't see anything on the console window when I run my game. So what does this mean?

Comment: Well that means that the movement that got the enemy is less than 0.2f please check that it's not the same position, It could be happening that is not moving because it gets the same position and probably it's the only possible movement.

Comment: I'm sorry Chopi, I'm not sure exactly what you are saying. I've checked through the code and all values are set to 0.2f. I'm not even sure that this will even work based on what I see when I run the game. I've noticed that because the level is a maze, if the enemy gets a coordinate that is not very linear then the enemy will get stuck completely at the wall trying  to get to point B. Is there a way to use paths instead of way points and still be able to move to random points within the path? I really appreciate your extensive help, I hope I'm not taking much of your time. Thanks!

Comment: You can try with the navigation ai https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html

Comment: Hi Chopi, I haven't forgotten about you. I've been following some examples from the AStart Project packaged in Unity. Thanks for the suggestion using Path finding as an approach. So far I have most of the implementations done but I have a slight problem that I might be overlooking. If your up to it, I can send you the details/links when I get the chance. I've marked your answer correct so you can have the credit.

Comment: @user1656528 thanks!! I haven't worked too much with the Navigation AI so it's better to leave a new question, I usually check questions to help people :)

Comment: Awesome! I have posted a new question which will hopefully generate all of the answers I need in order to get moving again with my project. : / Link to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224819/unity-2d-a-pathfinding-project-how-to-make-ai-object-patrol-to-random-points