# Unity 2d A* pathfinding project: how to make ai object patrol to random points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

As the title states this question refers to the Unity A* pathfinding project. I downloaded this package for my maze game so that the enemy's ai could navigate through the maze. So far I have followed a tutorial (**link will be provided below**) and everything is set up. However, I don't seem to know how to implement ray casting or another method to make the enemy patrol to a random point in a continuous loop.

[A* Tutorial Link](http://hobblygobbly.tumblr.com/post/93960257057/how-to-setup-the-a-pathfinding-project-in-a-2d)

**Note:** *There is a problem with my current set up though, which I have no clue if it will affect your answer from working correctly.*

For some reason when I run my game the enemy ai does move towards the targeted area but after a few inches it stops prematurely even thought it is far from the target's location and it is not colliding with any other objects.

**Seeker Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
#if UNITY_5_5_OR_NEWER
using UnityEngine.Profiling;
#endif

namespace Pathfinding {
    /** Handles path calls for a single unit.
     * \ingroup relevant
     * This is a component which is meant to be attached to a single unit (AI, Robot, Player, whatever) to handle its pathfinding calls.
     * It also handles post-processing of paths using modifiers.
     *
     * \shadowimage{seeker_inspector.png}
     *
     * \see \ref calling-pathfinding
     * \see \ref modifiers
     */
    [AddComponentMenu("Pathfinding/Seeker")]
    [HelpURL("http://arongranberg.com/astar/docs/class_pathfinding_1_1_seeker.php")]
    public class Seeker : VersionedMonoBehaviour {
        /** Enables drawing of the last calculated path using Gizmos.
         * The path will show up in green.
         *
         * \see OnDrawGizmos
         */
        public bool drawGizmos = true;

        /** Enables drawing of the non-postprocessed path using Gizmos.
         * The path will show up in orange.
         *
         * Requires that #drawGizmos is true.
         *
         * This will show the path before any post processing such as smoothing is applied.
         *
         * \see drawGizmos
         * \see OnDrawGizmos
         */
        public bool detailedGizmos;

        /** Path modifier which tweaks the start and end points of a path */
        [HideInInspector]
        public StartEndModifier startEndModifier = new StartEndModifier();

        /** The tags which the Seeker can traverse.
         *
         * \note This field is a bitmask.
         * \see \ref bitmasks
         */
        [HideInInspector]
        public int traversableTags = -1;

        /** Penalties for each tag.
         * Tag 0 which is the default tag, will have added a penalty of tagPenalties[0].
         * These should only be positive values since the A* algorithm cannot handle negative penalties.
         *
         * \note This array should always have a length of 32 otherwise the system will ignore it.
         *
         * \see Pathfinding.Path.tagPenalties
         */
        [HideInInspector]
        public int[] tagPenalties = new int[32];

        /** Graphs that this Seeker can use.
         * This field determines which graphs will be considered when searching for the start and end nodes of a path.
         * It is useful in numerous situations, for example if you want to make one graph for small units and one graph for large units.
         *
         * This is a bitmask so if you for example want to make the agent only use graph index 3 then you can set this to:
         * \code seeker.graphMask = 1 << 3; \endcode
         *
         * \see \ref bitmasks
         *
         * Note that this field only stores which graph indices that are allowed. This means that if the graphs change their ordering
         * then this mask may no longer be correct.
         *
         * If you know the name of the graph you can set the mask like this:
         * \snippet MiscSnippets.cs Masks.FromGraphName
         *
         * Some overloads of the #StartPath methods take a graphMask parameter. If those overloads are used then they
         * will override the graph mask for that path request.
         *
         * \shadowimage{multiple_agents/seeker.png}
         *
         * \see \ref multiple-agent-types
         */
        [HideInInspector]
        public int graphMask = -1;

        /** Callback for when a path is completed.
         * Movement scripts should register to this delegate.\n
         * A temporary callback can also be set when calling StartPath, but that delegate will only be called for that path
         */
        public OnPathDelegate pathCallback;

        /** Called before pathfinding is started */
        public OnPathDelegate preProcessPath;

        /** Called after a path has been calculated, right before modifiers are executed.
         */
        public OnPathDelegate postProcessPath;

        /** Used for drawing gizmos */
        [System.NonSerialized]
        List<Vector3> lastCompletedVectorPath;

        /** Used for drawing gizmos */
        [System.NonSerialized]
        List<GraphNode> lastCompletedNodePath;

        /** The current path */
        [System.NonSerialized]
        protected Path path;

        /** Previous path. Used to draw gizmos */
        [System.NonSerialized]
        private Path prevPath;

        /** Cached delegate to avoid allocating one every time a path is started */
        private readonly OnPathDelegate onPathDelegate;

        /** Temporary callback only called for the current path. This value is set by the StartPath functions */
        private OnPathDelegate tmpPathCallback;

        /** The path ID of the last path queried */
        protected uint lastPathID;

        /** Internal list of all modifiers */
        readonly List<IPathModifier> modifiers = new List<IPathModifier>();

        public enum ModifierPass {
            PreProcess,
            // An obsolete item occupied index 1 previously
            PostProcess = 2,
        }

        public Seeker () {
            onPathDelegate = OnPathComplete;
        }

        /** Initializes a few variables */
        protected override void Awake () {
            base.Awake();
            startEndModifier.Awake(this);
        }

        /** Path that is currently being calculated or was last calculated.
         * You should rarely have to use this. Instead get the path when the path callback is called.
         *
         * \see pathCallback
         */
        public Path GetCurrentPath () {
            return path;
        }

        /** Stop calculating the current path request.
         * If this Seeker is currently calculating a path it will be canceled.
         * The callback (usually to a method named OnPathComplete) will soon be called
         * with a path that has the 'error' field set to true.
         *
         * This does not stop the character from moving, it just aborts
         * the path calculation.
         *
         * \param pool If true then the path will be pooled when the pathfinding system is done with it.
         */
        public void CancelCurrentPathRequest (bool pool = true) {
            if (!IsDone()) {
                path.FailWithError("Canceled by script (Seeker.CancelCurrentPathRequest)");
                if (pool) {
                    // Make sure the path has had its reference count incremented and decremented once.
                    // If this is not done the system will think no pooling is used at all and will not pool the path.
                    // The particular object that is used as the parameter (in this case 'path') doesn't matter at all
                    // it just has to be *some* object.
                    path.Claim(path);
                    path.Release(path);
                }
            }
        }

        /** Cleans up some variables.
         * Releases any eventually claimed paths.
         * Calls OnDestroy on the #startEndModifier.
         *
         * \see ReleaseClaimedPath
         * \see startEndModifier
         */
        public void OnDestroy () {
            ReleaseClaimedPath();
            startEndModifier.OnDestroy(this);
        }

        /** Releases the path used for gizmos (if any).
         * The seeker keeps the latest path claimed so it can draw gizmos.
         * In some cases this might not be desireable and you want it released.
         * In that case, you can call this method to release it (not that path gizmos will then not be drawn).
         *
         * If you didn't understand anything from the description above, you probably don't need to use this method.
         *
         * \see \ref pooling
         */
        public void ReleaseClaimedPath () {
            if (prevPath != null) {
                prevPath.Release(this, true);
                prevPath = null;
            }
        }

        /** Called by modifiers to register themselves */
        public void RegisterModifier (IPathModifier modifier) {
            modifiers.Add(modifier);

            // Sort the modifiers based on their specified order
            modifiers.Sort((a, b) => a.Order.CompareTo(b.Order));
        }

        /** Called by modifiers when they are disabled or destroyed */
        public void DeregisterModifier (IPathModifier modifier) {
            modifiers.Remove(modifier);
        }

        /** Post Processes the path.
         * This will run any modifiers attached to this GameObject on the path.
         * This is identical to calling RunModifiers(ModifierPass.PostProcess, path)
         * \see RunModifiers
         * \since Added in 3.2
         */
        public void PostProcess (Path path) {
            RunModifiers(ModifierPass.PostProcess, path);
        }

        /** Runs modifiers on a path */
        public void RunModifiers (ModifierPass pass, Path path) {
            if (pass == ModifierPass.PreProcess) {
                if (preProcessPath != null) preProcessPath(path);

                for (int i = 0; i < modifiers.Count; i++) modifiers[i].PreProcess(path);
            } else if (pass == ModifierPass.PostProcess) {
                Profiler.BeginSample("Running Path Modifiers");
                // Call delegates if they exist
                if (postProcessPath != null) postProcessPath(path);

                // Loop through all modifiers and apply post processing
                for (int i = 0; i < modifiers.Count; i++) modifiers[i].Apply(path);
                Profiler.EndSample();
            }
        }

        /** Is the current path done calculating.
         * Returns true if the current #path has been returned or if the #path is null.
         *
         * \note Do not confuse this with Pathfinding.Path.IsDone. They usually return the same value, but not always
         * since the path might be completely calculated, but it has not yet been processed by the Seeker.
         *
         * \since Added in 3.0.8
         * \version Behaviour changed in 3.2
         */
        public bool IsDone () {
            return path == null || path.PipelineState >= PathState.Returned;
        }

        /** Called when a path has completed.
         * This should have been implemented as optional parameter values, but that didn't seem to work very well with delegates (the values weren't the default ones)
         * \see OnPathComplete(Path,bool,bool)
         */
        void OnPathComplete (Path path) {
            OnPathComplete(path, true, true);
        }

        /** Called when a path has completed.
         * Will post process it and return it by calling #tmpPathCallback and #pathCallback
         */
        void OnPathComplete (Path p, bool runModifiers, bool sendCallbacks) {
            if (p != null && p != path && sendCallbacks) {
                return;
            }

            if (this == null || p == null || p != path)
                return;

            if (!path.error && runModifiers) {
                // This will send the path for post processing to modifiers attached to this Seeker
                RunModifiers(ModifierPass.PostProcess, path);
            }

            if (sendCallbacks) {
                p.Claim(this);

                lastCompletedNodePath = p.path;
                lastCompletedVectorPath = p.vectorPath;

                // This will send the path to the callback (if any) specified when calling StartPath
                if (tmpPathCallback != null) {
                    tmpPathCallback(p);
                }

                // This will send the path to any script which has registered to the callback
                if (pathCallback != null) {
                    pathCallback(p);
                }

                // Recycle the previous path to reduce the load on the GC
                if (prevPath != null) {
                    prevPath.Release(this, true);
                }

                prevPath = p;

                // If not drawing gizmos, then storing prevPath is quite unecessary
                // So clear it and set prevPath to null
                if (!drawGizmos) ReleaseClaimedPath();
            }
        }


        /** Returns a new path instance.
         * The path will be taken from the path pool if path recycling is turned on.\n
         * This path can be sent to #StartPath(Path,OnPathDelegate,int) with no change, but if no change is required #StartPath(Vector3,Vector3,OnPathDelegate) does just that.
         * \code
         * var seeker = GetComponent<Seeker>();
         * Path p = seeker.GetNewPath (transform.position, transform.position+transform.forward*100);
         * // Disable heuristics on just this path for example
         * p.heuristic = Heuristic.None;
         * seeker.StartPath (p, OnPathComplete);
         * \endcode
         * \deprecated Use ABPath.Construct(start, end, null) instead.
         */
        [System.Obsolete("Use ABPath.Construct(start, end, null) instead")]
        public ABPath GetNewPath (Vector3 start, Vector3 end) {
            // Construct a path with start and end points
            return ABPath.Construct(start, end, null);
        }

        /** Call this function to start calculating a path.
         * Since this method does not take a callback parameter, you should set the #pathCallback field before calling this method.
         *
         * \param start     The start point of the path
         * \param end       The end point of the path
         */
        public Path StartPath (Vector3 start, Vector3 end) {
            return StartPath(start, end, null);
        }

        /** Call this function to start calculating a path.
         *
         * \param start     The start point of the path
         * \param end       The end point of the path
         * \param callback  The function to call when the path has been calculated
         *
         * \a callback will be called when the path has completed.
         * \a Callback will not be called if the path is canceled (e.g when a new path is requested before the previous one has completed) */
        public Path StartPath (Vector3 start, Vector3 end, OnPathDelegate callback) {
            return StartPath(ABPath.Construct(start, end, null), callback);
        }

        /** Call this function to start calculating a path.
         *
         * \param start     The start point of the path
         * \param end       The end point of the path
         * \param callback  The function to call when the path has been calculated
         * \param graphMask Mask used to specify which graphs should be searched for close nodes. See #Pathfinding.NNConstraint.graphMask. This will override #graphMask for this path request.
         *
         * \a callback will be called when the path has completed.
         * \a Callback will not be called if the path is canceled (e.g when a new path is requested before the previous one has completed) */
        public Path StartPath (Vector3 start, Vector3 end, OnPathDelegate callback, int graphMask) {
            return StartPath(ABPath.Construct(start, end, null), callback, graphMask);
        }

        /** Call this function to start calculating a path.
         *
         * \param p         The path to start calculating
         * \param callback  The function to call when the path has been calculated
         *
         * The \a callback will be called when the path has been calculated (which may be several frames into the future).
         * The \a callback will not be called if a new path request is started before this path request has been calculated.
         *
         * \version Since 3.8.3 this method works properly if a MultiTargetPath is used.
         * It now behaves identically to the StartMultiTargetPath(MultiTargetPath) method.
         *
         * \version Since 4.1.x this method will no longer overwrite the graphMask on the path unless it is explicitly passed as a parameter (see other overloads of this method).
         */
        public Path StartPath (Path p, OnPathDelegate callback = null) {
            // Set the graph mask only if the user has not changed it from the default value.
            // This is not perfect as the user may have wanted it to be precisely -1
            // however it is the best detection that I can do.
            // The non-default check is primarily for compatibility reasons to avoid breaking peoples existing code.
            // The StartPath overloads with an explicit graphMask field should be used instead to set the graphMask.
            if (p.nnConstraint.graphMask == -1) p.nnConstraint.graphMask = graphMask;
            StartPathInternal(p, callback);
            return p;
        }

        /** Call this function to start calculating a path.
         *
         * \param p         The path to start calculating
         * \param callback  The function to call when the path has been calculated
         * \param graphMask Mask used to specify which graphs should be searched for close nodes. See #Pathfinding.NNConstraint.graphMask. This will override #graphMask for this path request.
         *
         * The \a callback will be called when the path has been calculated (which may be several frames into the future).
         * The \a callback will not be called if a new path request is started before this path request has been calculated.
         *
         * \version Since 3.8.3 this method works properly if a MultiTargetPath is used.
         * It now behaves identically to the StartMultiTargetPath(MultiTargetPath) method.
         */
        public Path StartPath (Path p, OnPathDelegate callback, int graphMask) {
            p.nnConstraint.graphMask = graphMask;
            StartPathInternal(p, callback);
            return p;
        }

        /** Internal method to start a path and mark it as the currently active path */
        void StartPathInternal (Path p, OnPathDelegate callback) {
            p.callback += onPathDelegate;

            p.enabledTags = traversableTags;
            p.tagPenalties = tagPenalties;

            // Cancel a previously requested path is it has not been processed yet and also make sure that it has not been recycled and used somewhere else
            if (path != null && path.PipelineState <= PathState.Processing && path.CompleteState != PathCompleteState.Error && lastPathID == path.pathID) {
                path.FailWithError("Canceled path because a new one was requested.\n"+
                    "This happens when a new path is requested from the seeker when one was already being calculated.\n" +
                    "For example if a unit got a new order, you might request a new path directly instead of waiting for the now" +
                    " invalid path to be calculated. Which is probably what you want.\n" +
                    "If you are getting this a lot, you might want to consider how you are scheduling path requests.");
                // No callback will be sent for the canceled path
            }

            // Set p as the active path
            path = p;
            tmpPathCallback = callback;

            // Save the path id so we can make sure that if we cancel a path (see above) it should not have been recycled yet.
            lastPathID = path.pathID;

            // Pre process the path
            RunModifiers(ModifierPass.PreProcess, path);

            // Send the request to the pathfinder
            AstarPath.StartPath(path);
        }


        /** Draws gizmos for the Seeker */
        public void OnDrawGizmos () {
            if (lastCompletedNodePath == null || !drawGizmos) {
                return;
            }

            if (detailedGizmos) {
                Gizmos.color = new Color(0.7F, 0.5F, 0.1F, 0.5F);

                if (lastCompletedNodePath != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lastCompletedNodePath.Count-1; i++) {
                        Gizmos.DrawLine((Vector3)lastCompletedNodePath[i].position, (Vector3)lastCompletedNodePath[i+1].position);
                    }
                }
            }

            Gizmos.color = new Color(0, 1F, 0, 1F);

            if (lastCompletedVectorPath != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < lastCompletedVectorPath.Count-1; i++) {
                    Gizmos.DrawLine(lastCompletedVectorPath[i], lastCompletedVectorPath[i+1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AStar AI Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
//Note this line, if it is left out, the script won't know that the class 'Path' exists and it will throw compiler errors
//This line should always be present at the top of scripts which use pathfinding
using Pathfinding;

public class AstarAI : MonoBehaviour
{
  //The point to move to
  public Transform target;

  private Seeker seeker;

  //The calculated path
  public Path path;

  //The AI's speed per second
  public float speed = 2;

  //The max distance from the AI to a waypoint for it to continue to the next waypoint
  public float nextWaypointDistance = 3;

  //The waypoint we are currently moving towards
  private int currentWaypoint = 0;

  public void Start ()
  {
    seeker = GetComponent<Seeker>();

    //Start a new path to the targetPosition, return the result to the OnPathComplete function
    seeker.StartPath( transform.position, target.position, OnPathComplete );
  }

  public void OnPathComplete ( Path p )
  {
    Debug.Log( "Yay, we got a path back. Did it have an error? " + p.error );
    if (!p.error)
    {
      path = p;
      //Reset the waypoint counter
      currentWaypoint = 0;
    }
  }

  public void FixedUpdate ()
  {
    if (path == null)
    {
      //We have no path to move after yet
      return;
    }

    if (currentWaypoint >= path.vectorPath.Count)
    {
      Debug.Log( "End Of Path Reached" );
      return;
    }

    //Direction to the next waypoint
    Vector3 dir = ( path.vectorPath[ currentWaypoint ] - transform.position ).normalized;
    dir *= speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    this.gameObject.transform.Translate( dir );

    //Check if we are close enough to the next waypoint
    //If we are, proceed to follow the next waypoint
    if (Vector3.Distance( transform.position, path.vectorPath[ currentWaypoint ] ) < nextWaypointDistance)
    {
      currentWaypoint++;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

If you need additional information please let me know.

All help would greatly be appreciated!

**Enemy Ai Component Capture:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet within your answer? This is a programming Q/A site, after all. If you're confused on what makes a question worthwhile, [check here to learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Scripts have been added

Comment: Try enabling the Gizmos render layer by checking Gizmos to see if anything is out of place. Also, check your console. Might be some sort of log telling you what's going on. I also recommend you debug your code. Throw in some breakpoints and see what is called when your enemy stops short, try and trace the issue back. I can't test this stuff myself as I'm at work, so I don't have access to my Unity Editor. :/

Comment: Hi James, I'm going to conduct a breakpoint experiment and let you know what I find. So far, when I run the game and look through the console this is what shows. Assets/AstarPathfindingProject/PackageTools/Editor/EnumFlagDrawer.cs(14,29): warning CS0618: `UnityEditor.EditorGUI.EnumMaskField(UnityEngine.Rect, UnityEngine.GUIContent, System.Enum)' is obsolete: `EnumMaskField has been deprecated. Use EnumFlagsField instead.'